# Need to Pull result from last year into inventory usage report

Tags: t-sql, inventory, sapb1

I have an inventory usage report that pulls in transactions from the previous year. Right now I have results for the current year. What is the correct date syntax for me to use?

Below is what I have currently for this year I am using the get date function for this year and need it to calculate the same information, but break it down monthly for last year.

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName AS 'Description', OITM.CardCode AS 
'Vendor',
SUM(OITW.OnHand) AS 'On Hand', SUM(OITW.OnOrder) AS 'On Order', 
SUM(OITW.IsCommited) AS 'Committed',

(SUM(OITW.OnHand)+SUM(OITW.OnOrder)-SUM(OITW.IsCommited)) AS 'Available', 
OITM.AvgPrice AS 'Unit Cost',(SUM(OITW.OnHand)*OITM.AvgPrice) AS 'Value $',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=((year, -1, GETDATE()) AND OINM.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode 
GROUP BY

OINM.ItemCode) AS 'Prev. Year',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='1' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=(year, -1, GETDATE()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'JAN',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='2' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=(year, -1, GETDATE()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'FEB',  
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='3' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'MAR',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='4' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'APR',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='5' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'MAY',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='6' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'JUN',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='7' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'JUL',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='8' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'AUG',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='9' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'SEP',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='10' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'OCT',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='11' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'NOV',
(SELECT SUM(OINM.OutQty) FROM OINM WHERE OINM.TransType <> '67' AND 
MONTH(OINM.DocDate)='12' AND YEAR(OINM.DocDate)=YEAR(getdate()) AND 
OINM.ItemCode =

OITM.ItemCode GROUP BY OINM.ItemCode) AS 'DEC'
FROM OITM, OITW
WHERE OITM.ItemCode=OITW.ItemCode
```

Comment: Please post the complete Code (that works). This can't work without a `GROUP BY` clause. Also, you maybe could explain what you are trying to achieve. The previous year is `YEAR(GETDATE())-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to shorten the original query a bit. If I'm not completely wrong, it can be written as follows:

```
WITH 
  OINM_Base (ItemCode, [Month], OutQty) AS (
    SELECT 
      ItemCode,
      CASE GROUPING(MONTH(DocDate))
        WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE MONTH(DocDate)
      END,
      SUM(OutQty)
    FROM OINM
    WHERE TransType <> '67' AND YEAR(DocDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) -- change this for the previous year
    GROUP BY ItemCode, ROLLUP(MONTH(DocDate))
  ),
  OINM_Data (ItemCode, [Year], JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, [DEC]) AS (
    SELECT ItemCode, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
    FROM OINM_Base
    PIVOT (SUM(OutQty) FOR [Month] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])) pvt
  ),
  OITW_Data (ItemCode, [On Hand], [On Order], [Committed]) AS (
    SELECT ItemCode, SUM(OnHand), SUM(OnOrder), SUM(IsCommited)
    FROM OITW
    GROUP BY ItemCode
  )
SELECT
  tm.ItemCode,
  tm.ItemName AS [Description],
  tm.CardCode AS Vendor,
  tw.[On Hand], tw.[On Order], tw.[Committed],
  tw.[On Hand] + tw.[On Order] - tw.[Committed] AS Available,
  tm.AvgPrice AS [Unit Cost],
  tw.[On Hand] * tm.AvgPrice AS [Value $],
  nm.[Year], nm.JAN, nm.FEB, nm.MAR, nm.APR, nm.MAY, nm.JUN, nm.JUL, nm.AUG, nm.SEP, nm.OCT, nm.NOV, nm.[DEC]
FROM OITM tm
  INNER JOIN OITW_Data tw ON tm.ItemCode = tw.ItemCode
  LEFT OUTER JOIN OINM_Data nm ON tm.ItemCode = nm.ItemCode;
```

This works as follows:

The data in `OINM` is restricted to the year in question, summing the `OutQty` values per month and creating a total for the year which is labelled as month number 0 (CTE `OINM_Base`). Using a `PIVOT` query, the sums appearing on different rows are turned into columns (CTE `OINM_Data`). The aggregation for the OITW data is also done saparately (CTE `OITW_Data`).

Both `OINM_Data` and `OITW_Data` are finally joined with the data building the main rows from `OITM`. Here, the final calculations are done (`Available` and `Value $`).

Now, to change the query to return the previous year, only one thing has to be changed (see my comment "*change this for the previous year*"), namely :

`YEAR(GETDATE())` has to be replaced by `YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1`.

Comment: Thank you, I am getting the following message Msg 252, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Recursive common table expression 'OINM_Data' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, that should have been OINM_Base.  I'll correct that immediately.

Comment: It runs correctly in SQL but whenever i try to run it in SAP Business one i get the following error message 'incorrect syntax near the word for'

Comment: Sorry for that, maybe you can create a view in SQL Server and query that through SAP.

Comment: Got it :) Thank you so much!!